# Clickable second td of the table not working

Tags: jquery, events

There is a table with tbody id of: table_tbody 
I am trying to add 10 rows with clickable second td in jquery.
I have created one variable: `element` which is the `<tr>` row with included `<td>`s.

This is the part of the code.

```
for (var ind = 0; ind < 10; ++ind) {
   var elem = element.clone();
   elem.children().next().first().attr("id", "table_td" + ind.toString());
   $("#table_td" + ind.toString()).click({playerID: 0}, playerFunc);
   $('#table_tbody').append(elem);
}
```

As you see I am setting unique id for each row's second `td`.
Then I am connecting to it the click event. However the click event is not firing after I click on it. 
No errors are shown.

Am I doing it incorrectly?

EDIT: [Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahzzK/)

Comment: Please show your `element` variable and how looks your HTML initially before you start the cloning...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Please look at update (edit added)

Comment: `$("#table_td"+ i).click({playerID: 0}, playerFunc);` what's this `playerID: 0` supposed to do?

Comment: I wanted to pass parameter to playerFunc so that I know the ID of player of whose info is showed in the row. (now it is zero but in future it will be calculated some way)

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you [might want to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) look at using `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up the instruction sequence a bit;)

```
$("#table_td" + ind.toString())
```

looks for the element in the DOM tree and it doesn't find it, since you haven't added it yet. You need to append the element first, and then you can add the event listener. This should work:

```
for (var ind = 0; ind < 10; ++ind) {
  var elem = element.clone();
  elem.children().next().first().attr("id", "table_td" + ind.toString());
  $('#table_tbody').append(elem);
  $("#table_td" + ind.toString()).click({playerID: 0}, playerFunc);
}
```

Comment: That is dead on imo. `elem.find("#table_td" + ind.toString());` is a direct alternative since it searches the yet temporary, cloned DOM-element.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the edit with JSFiddle. Like @Roko mentioned playerFunc definition is out of scope - move it before the for loop and it should work

Answer (score 3):

The ideal way is to use `class` instead of `id`.

```
for (var ind = 0; ind < 10; ++ind) {
   var elem = element.clone();
   elem.children().next().first().attr("class", "table_td");       
   $('#table_tbody').append(elem);
}

$(document).on('click', '.table_td', function(){
    playerFunc();
});
```

Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/ahzzK/6/

Answer (score 2):

See this:

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahzzK/5/)

playerFunc was not defined on for.

```
function playerFunc (){
    alert("hren" + this.playerID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply the Question what was first on earth .. egg or chicken

```
for (var ind = 0; ind < 10; ++ind) {
  var elem = element.clone();
  elem.children().next().first().attr("id", "table_td" + ind.toString());
  $('#table_tbody').append(elem);
  $("#table_td" + ind.toString()).click({playerID: 0}, playerFunc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `.toString()` when you actually already add to string `"string"+ num`

Use the `.on()` method with delegation for dynamically generated elements,

No need to create `click` handlers inside the `for` guy

Target every 2nd element using `:odd` selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/ahzzK/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var playerFunc = function() { // Function scope!
        alert("hren");
    }


    var element = $("<tr>")
              .append( $("<td />", {"text":"bla1"}) )
              .append( $("<td />", {"text":"bla2"}) );

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
       var elem = element.clone();
       elem.children().next().first().attr("id", "table_td"+ i );
       $('#table_tbody').append(elem);
    }

    $("#table_tbody").on('click', 'td:odd', playerFunc );

});
```

Comment: What if I want only the second <td> to be clickable and there are more than one <td>s in the row?